# How do I merge accounts?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I am trying to merge two accounts.  I received these instructions:

> If you're not able to use the OpenID service that is tied to your account, please click the 'sign up' link at the top of the page and create a new account using a working service that you can access. Once you've done that, please edit the 'about me' section of the new profile to say 'merge delete' then complete and return the following short form:

The problem?  I do not see an *about me* or anything with the word *merge* in it anywhere.

Note to Stack Overflow staff: when you give some one directions it is not very effective to start in the middle of a process and **hope** they find where ever it is that you started.  It is wise to give direction starting at the beginning.

Anyone know what they are talking about or where this mysterious merge is hidden?

Let me click on Stack Exchange, NOPE!
Maybe my inbox,  NOPE!
How about help?  There's an About us, NOPE!
Maybe my picture, hey here's more stuff, maybe my profile,  NOPE!
Edit profile,  NOPE!
for the heck of it I can try activity,  NOPE!
Developer story,  NOPE!

Are the Stack Overflow instructions useless? YES!

Comment: Questions about SO itself belong on [meta]. This site is for programming related questions. When you move it there, you might strongly consider making it more of a question and less of a rant.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an amazing resource, which we get for free, but it is not perfect, just like any other human endeavour. I hope Stack Exchange staff (and the community, who work for free) do not tolerate your abuse of them.

Comment: You can edit your 'About me' section [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/2282805).

Comment: Why would you see the word merge? You're expected to *add* the word merge, along with the word delete, to the section with the specified name that *is* in one of the places you claim to have looked.

Comment: That only proves how unclear this operation is. So I put merge delete in the same place?  That is bizarre at best.  I will try it but I suspect there are other unintuitive things that need to be done so I will probably fail.

Comment: @Ken whats a [meta]?  I would be happy to put it in the right place but you gotta give me more than a clue.  Directions or a location works.

Comment: @halfer stackoverflow isn't so great, its the people who are great.  If stackoverflow disappeared tomorrow the people would just go somewhere else and make somewhere else great.

Comment: I think you're approaching this with the wrong attitude. The first the community sees of your difficulty is patronising rudeness, and lots of shouty "NOPE". Then you've written the process off as "bizarre", which is one of those loaded words designed to render someone else at (obvious and extreme) fault. Having tried to offend those people, you are presumably in the awkward position of still wanting help. My advice - which is meant to be productive and helpful - is to edit your question above so it is kinder and more diplomatic.

Answer (score 8):

> [image]

Comment: -1, no freehand circles.

Comment: @Glorfindel Partial credit for freehand lines?

Comment: (: Some dark stuff is spilling out your ear on the picture... I guess your head can't hold all we write on SO :)

Comment: @Glorfindel but there's a freehand line, that's just as good